# is this a memory allocation issue?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

i have been working on a custome programming language lately, i have implemented things like arrays and variables into the custome language uing c flex(lexer generator) and bison(parser generator), i have successfully managed to make the variables and arrays(1 dimentional arrays) work the issue i noticed appearing when i try to store a value stored in a index of the 2 dimentional array into the variable, here is the parser

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashtable.h"
int array_size;
int twod_array_size_row;
int twod_array_size_col;
%}

%union {
   int num;
   char *str;
   struct ast *ast_node;
   struct symlist *arg_list;
}

%token <str> EQUALS
%token <str> SEMICOLON
%token <str> PLUS
%token <str> MINUS
%token <str> MULTIPLY
%token <str> DIVIDE
%token  LPAR
%token  RPAR
%token <str> LCB
%token <str> RCB
%token  MAIN
%token <str> CALL
%token VAR

%token <num> NUMBER
%token <str> IDENT
%token <str> LSB
%token <str> RSB
%token <str> COMMA

%type <num> expr
%type <str> var_declaration assignment display
%type <str> statement_list


%left PLUS MINUS
%left MULTIPLY DIVIDE

%%

mainprog: MAIN LCB statement_list RCB SEMICOLON;

statement_list: /* empty */
              | statement_list statement SEMICOLON
              ;

statement: var_declaration | assignment | display;

var_declaration:  IDENT LSB expr RSB { insert_array($1,$3); array_size = $3;}
               | VAR IDENT { insert_variable($2); }
           | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB {insert_2d_array($1, $3, $6);twod_array_size_col=$6; twod_array_size_row=$3;};

assignment: IDENT EQUALS expr { update_variable($1, $3); }
          | IDENT LSB expr RSB EQUALS expr { update_array_element($1, $3, $6,array_size); }
          | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB EQUALS expr { update_2d_array_element($1, $3, $6, $9,twod_array_size_row,twod_array_size_col); };

display: CALL IDENT { display_variable($2); }
       | CALL IDENT LSB expr RSB { display_array_element($2, $4,array_size); }
       | CALL IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB { display_2d_array_element($2, $4, $7,twod_array_size_row,twod_array_size_col); };





expr: NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
   | IDENT { $$ = get_variable_value($1); }
   | IDENT LSB expr RSB { $$ = get_array_element_value($1, $3,array_size); }
   | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB {get_2d_array_element_value($1, $6, $3, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col);}
   | expr PLUS expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
   | expr MINUS expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
   | expr MULTIPLY expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
   | expr DIVIDE expr {
       if ($3 != 0) {
           $$ = $1 / $3;
       } else {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error: Division by zero\n");
           $$ = 0; // You can handle division by zero differently if needed
       }
   }
   | '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
   ;
   %%
   void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
}
```

the lexer:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
char* yytext;
%}

DIGIT      [0-9]
WS         [ \t\n]
IDENT     [a-zA-Z]

%%

{WS}       /* Ignore whitespace */
{DIGIT}+   { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
{IDENT}+  { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return IDENT; }
"+"        {  return PLUS; }
"-"        {  return MINUS; }
"*"        {  return MULTIPLY;}
"/"        {  return DIVIDE;}
"="        {  return EQUALS;}
";"        { return SEMICOLON;}
"("        {  return LPAR; }
")"        { return RPAR; }
"{"        {  return LCB; }
"}"        {  return RCB; }
"["        { return LSB;}
"]"        {return RSB ;}

"##".*      {  }
"/#"[^#]*"#/" {  }
"@var"     {return VAR;}
"Void Main()"  { return MAIN;}  
"@call"        {return CALL;}
.          { fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unexpected character '%s'\n", yytext); }

%%

int yywrap() {
   return 1;
}
```

and the functionality used for the lexer and parser is here: hashtable.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashtable.h"

#define HASH_SIZE 101

struct Node {
    char *name;
    int is_array;  // Indicates whether the variable is an array
    void *value;   // Value can be int or int array
    int size;      // Size of the array
    int rows;
    int cols;
    struct Node *next;
};

static struct Node *hash_table[HASH_SIZE];

unsigned int hash(const char *str) {
    unsigned int hash_val = 0;
    while (*str) {
        hash_val = (hash_val << 5) + *str++;
    }
    return hash_val % HASH_SIZE;
}

void initialize_hashtable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; ++i) {
        hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void insert_variable(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->name = strdup(name);
    new_node->is_array = 0;
    new_node->value = malloc(sizeof(int));  // Allocate space for single int
    if (new_node->value == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        free(new_node->name);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    *((int *)new_node->value) = 0;  // Default value
    new_node->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = new_node;
}

void insert_array(const char *name, int array_size) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->name = strdup(name);
    new_node->is_array = 1;
    new_node->size = array_size;
    new_node->value = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));  // Allocate space for the array
    if (new_node->value == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        free(new_node->name);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        ((int *)new_node->value)[i] = 0;  // Default values for the array
    }
    new_node->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = new_node;
}
void insert_2d_array(const char *name, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);
    
    printf("Inserting 2D array: %s[%d][%d]\n", name, rows, cols);  // Debugging print
    
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->name = strdup(name);
    new_node->is_array = 1;
    new_node->rows = rows;
    new_node->cols = cols;
    new_node->size = rows * cols;
    new_node->value = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *)); // Allocate space for rows
    if (new_node->value == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        free(new_node->name);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    // Initialize all row pointers to NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        ((int **)new_node->value)[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        ((int **)new_node->value)[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int)); // Allocate space for columns
        if (((int **)new_node->value)[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
            // Free previously allocated memory
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
                free(((int **)new_node->value)[j]);
            }
            free(new_node->value);
            free(new_node->name);
            free(new_node);
            return;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            ((int **)new_node->value)[i][j] = i * cols + j;  // Debug: Assign unique value to each element
        }
    }
    new_node->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = new_node;
}

void update_variable(const char *name, int value) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0) {
            if (current->is_array) {
                if (current->rows == 0) {
                    // 1D Array
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot update a variable with a value from a 1D array\n");
                    return;
                } else {
                    // 2D Array
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot update a variable with a value from a 2D array\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
            *((int *)current->value) = value;
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared\n", name);
}

void update_array_element(const char *name, int index, int value, int array_size) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < current->size) {
                ((int *)current->value)[index] = value;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not an array\n", name);
}

void update_2d_array_element(const char *name, int row, int col, int value, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (row >= 0 && row < current->rows && col >= 0 && col < current->cols) {
                ((int **)current->value)[row][col] = value;
                printf("the value is: %d\n", ((int **)current->value)[row][col]);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: 2D Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return; // Exiting the function after updating the array element
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not a 2D array\n", name);
    // Optionally, you could add an error message here or handle the error condition differently
}





int get_variable_value(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && !current->is_array) {
            return *((int *)current->value);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared\n", name);
    return 0;  // Return a default value
}

int get_array_element_value(const char *name, int index, int array_size) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < current->size) {
                return ((int *)current->value)[index];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Array index out of bounds\n");
                return 0;  // Return a default value
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not an array\n", name);
    return 0;  // Return a default value
}

int get_2d_array_element_value(const char *name, int row, int col, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (row >= 0 && row < current->rows && col >= 0 && col < current->cols) {
                return ((int **)current->value)[row][col];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: 2D Array index out of bounds\n");
                return 0;  // Return a default value
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not a 2D array\n", name);
    return 0;  // Return a default value
}


void display_variable(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && !current->is_array) {
            printf("%s = %d\n", name, *((int *)current->value));
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared\n", name);
}

void display_array_element(const char *name, int index, int array_size) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < current->size) {
                printf("%s[%d] = %d\n", name, index, ((int *)current->value)[index]);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not an array\n", name);
}

void display_2d_array_element(const char *name, int row, int col, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);
    
    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (row >= 0 && row < current->rows && col >= 0 && col < current->cols) {
                printf("%s[%d][%d] = %d\n", name, row, col, ((int **)current->value)[row][col]);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: 2D Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not a 2D array\n", name);
}
```

i tried to test those files with my syntax this code :

```
Void Main() {
    @var x;
    @var y;
    x = 10;
    y = 20;
    z[5];
    z[0] = 1;
    z[1] = 2;
    z[2] = 3;
    z[3] = 4;
    z[4] = 5;
    w[2][3];
    w[0][0] = 1;
    w[0][1] = 2;
    w[0][2] = 3;
    w[1][0] = 4;
    w[1][1] = 5;
    w[1][2] = 6;
    @call x;  ## Outputs: x = 10
    @call y;   ## Outputs: y = 20
    @call z[3]; ## Outputs: z[3] = 4
    @call w[1][2]; ## Outputs: w[1][2] = 6

    /#
    the issue is when i try to assign w[1][2] into a variable: 
    #/
    @var result;
    result = w[1][2];
    @call result; 
 /# result keeps printing out random numers each time i run the program, so i am suspecting that this is a memory allocation issue but i am not quiet sure #/
};
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you suggest a debugger?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should abstract out the whole "array" part. Right now you can only have one single 1d-array, and one single 2d-array. Think of arrays like in C. C doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, but you can have an array where each element is another array. This allows infinite nesting, and any number of "dimensions".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude according to my understanding IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB just runs the method get_2d_array_element_value with ident(array name) as $1 first expr expression as $3 and the second one as $6 the two last parameters are refering to two variables used to store the amount of rows and columns the array has! is this correct?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have just tested my code and i can define multiple 1d arrays without any issue, even store them into variables and it works fine, the issue starts when i use 2 d arrays

Comment: You can *define* multiple arrays. But you only have a single variable holding the size. What happens with the first array when you define a second array of a different size?

Comment: Also, on another unrelated note, please try to make variable declarations consistent. Having to use different syntaxes for different type of variables makes no sense. And I really recommend you see your arrays as actual variables, not a special case for your language.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i can define diffrent 1 d arrays with diffrent sizes without any issue

Comment: After reading more of your code, you seem to save the array size in the nodes, which is good. But then what is the single global `array_size` variable for? You seem to pass around the global variable to some functions, but it's not used in those functions. Why not simply remove it (and the 2d variants)? Make your code as simple as possible, that makes it easier to work with, debug and maintain. And of course easier for strangers like me to understand the code easier.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the rule

```
expr: ...
   | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB {get_2d_array_element_value($1, $6, $3, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col);}
   ...
```

The assignment rule expects `expr` to return a value, that `expr` should set `$$`.

The 1d-array access expression does that, but not the 2d-array expression.

You should (I assume) set `$$` to what `get_2d_array_element_value` returns:

```
   | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB { $$ = get_2d_array_element_value($1, $6, $3, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col); }
```

Answer (score -1):

i managed to fix the issue, it was an issue with :

```
IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB {$$ = get_2d_array_element_value($1, $3, $6, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col);}
```

and i placed the $3 and $6 in the wrong order which made the function return a error message that says array out of bounds, so everything worked the way i expected it to work after fixing those issues,i appreciate all the help i got, i think someone can close this question now !!

Comment: *Plus* the fact that you didn’t assign to `$$`.